# Video Card Recomendation for 4/quad monitors

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-graphics

Attempt #2 to run 4 monitors on Ubuntu with **open source drivers** and preferably with Utility.
Can someone recommend the best video card set up to run 4 HDMI monitors, set up is 2x2 with 1920x1080 on all monitors.

From research here are my current options:

1. One video card with 4 HDMI outputs. (Don't think these beast even
   exist?)
2. One video card with 4 DisplayPort outputs + 2 active DP to HDMI
   adapters. Are these supported by open source drivers?
3. Run two x2 HDMI NVIDIA/ATI cards side by side? Will there be an
   issue with drivers? Is Xinerama and TwinView still supported?
4. Mix and match, run one nvidia with x2 HDMI and one AMD? Will i be
   able to move windows across all monitors?

Comment: With the ATI cards Ubuntu would force the use of the generic drivers as it has for some reason blocked the AMD ATI Radeon drivers.  Because of that you should consider the Nvidia cards, plus using the Nvidia graphics driver.  The Nvidia graphics driver will give you greater control of each monitor individually and in combination.

Comment: Is there a significant reason you want open source drivers over proprietary? Nvidia has some really well-developed drivers for their cards, but the open source drives are really lacking.

Comment: This is going into a workstation so would like long term support that's why want OSS. Had a bad experience previously with closed drivers not being supported after a new kernel upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend my own configuration, identical to your request : Ubuntu 14.04 with 4 (up to 6) 1920*1080 monitors.

This is possible with a [ATI FirePro W600](https://www.google.fr/search?q=ATI+FirePro+600&oq=ATI+FirePro+600&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5152j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=ATI+FirePro+w600). According to your request, this worked out of the box with open-source driver.

I still have Unity and start looking at other window manager, like XMonad, but it's on a fine tweak part.

Like you I [spent time](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1647461) to look for acceptable configurations, and mentionned above is the easiest and most reliable I found. Working for 2 years+ like a charm, with good stability (8/10h a day).

Hope it helps,